# Passive 3D display

Tags: 3d-display

I can find 3D displays on Amazon, but the ones still sold all appear to be active ones. As active 3D always ghosted for me, passive 3D worked perfectly (I'm even more impressed if the Street Fighter IV demo I saw in a store was converted from 2D.), and again I just bought a new non-3D TV due to lack of <=48" supply, I'd like to replace my 1680x1050p 22" desktop monitor. 24" is fine, but if it would cost more than a 1080p phone with a gyroscope, I'd rather buy the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LG still sells a 49" model TV, the LG 49UH850V, which is UHD for 949 euro](https://www.tvs-vergelijken.nl/lg/5331-49uh850v.html), though it's tempting to get the 55" model for only 45 euro more. There is also the [Samsung UE50KU6020WXXN 50" UHD for 579 euro,](https://www.tvs-vergelijken.nl/samsung/5651-ue50ku6020wxxn.html) which [does not](https://www.androidplanet.nl/sony/xperia-z5-premium/) beat the price of a [VR-compatible smartphone](https://www.maxboxvr.com/phones-work-compatible-google-cardboard) with that resolution, but still offers 1080p in 25". I could then buy a new computer desk, or use my wireless keyboard at my dining tables.